# Solving a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: math, matlab, linear-algebra

How does one solve the (non-trivial) solution Ax = 0 for x in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)?

```
A = matrix
x = matrix trying to solve for
```

I've tried solve('A * x = 0', 'x')  but I only get 0 for an answer.

Comment: invertibility isn't particularly relevant (by itself).

Comment: if A is invertible, the only solution to Ax=0 is 0, no?

Comment: true, but this is a limited, special-case answer to a more general problem.

Comment: @Peter I think what manji is trying to say is that getting 0 is possibly the only valid result to OP particular case

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please note that null(A) does the same thing **(for a rank-deficient matrix)** as the following, but this is using the `svd(A)` function in MATLAB (which as I've mentioned in my comments is what `null(A)` does).

```
[U S V] = svd(A);
x = V(:,end)
```

For more about this, here's an [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Solving_homogeneous_linear_equations) related to this (can't post it to here due to the formulae).

If you want a more intuitive feel of singular and eigenvalue decompositions check out `eigshow` in MATLAB.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `N = null(A)` to get a matrix `N`. Any of the columns of `N` (or, indeed, any linear combination of columns of `N`) will satisfy `Ax = 0`. This describes all possible such `x` - you've just found an orthogonal basis for the nullspace of `A`.

Note: you can only find such an `x` if `A` has non-trivial nullspace. This will occur if `rank(A) < #cols of A`.

Comment: My rank(A) = # cols. How does one "lessen" the value of the rank ? Also null(A) = Empty matrix: 12-by-0.

Comment: You should look into low rank approximations. You can use the SVD for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can see if MATLAB has a singular value decomposition in its toolbox.  That will give you the null space of the vector.

Comment: That would be SVD, which results in the same result as null(A).

Comment: They use different numerical methods.

Comment: Not really, null(A) uses svd - http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/null.html

Comment: My apologies. I assumed it used the QR algorithm.

Comment: I've gone into more detail in my answer

Answer (score 0):

`null(A)` will give you the direct answer. If you need a nontrivial solution, try reduced row echelon form and refer the first page of the pdf.

```
R = rref(A)
```

http://www.math.colostate.edu/~gerhard/M345/CHP/ch7_4.pdf