# Linear combination of variating number of vectors

Tags: matlab

I have a variating number of vectors which have a linear dependency. I'd like to find the linear combination of coefficients which brings their sum to 0.
For example:

```
a*[1;1;1]+b[2;2;2]=0
a=2, b=-1
```

I could use iterators, but the number of vectors is changing and can be quite large.

Thanks

Comment: what approach are you using till now to find these coefficients?

Comment: I've used iterators which checked all possible options, but this is in case I know the number of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

You can use the [following approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1258171):

1. arrange the base vectors in columns
2. [Use SVD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520598/2955997) to calculate a non trivial solution.

**code**

```
%defines input
v1 = [1;1;1];
v2 = [2;2;2];

%perform calculation
[U S V] = svd([v1,v2]);
x = V(:,end)
```

**result**

```
v1*x(1)+v2*x(2)

ans =
 0
 0
 0

x =
0.8944
-0.4472
```

Comment: that is nice, but say I'd like to do it in galois field, svd doesn't work. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @OlegK If you want to do it in a Galois field that completely changes the question. You should definitely include that information in the question text